# Process for repairing flaking paint on fascia boards?

Tags: wood, painting, paint, caulking, sanding

The paint on my fascia boards is starting to flake off, especially where different boards meet. I wanted to make sure the process I have in mind looks right:

1. Sand fascia boards w/ 120 grit
2. **What kind of filler should I use to fill the gaps where the boards meet?** Should I use caulking or bondo?
3. Prime boards
4. Apply two coats of paint

[image]

Comment: Usually, paint is _scraped_ not _sanded_. This is because prior to 1978 (in the US), lead-based paint was commonly used in residences. It was available for non-residential use later than that and that may have been used in/on a residence. You don't want to sand lead-based paint and leave the dust floating in the atmosphere to be inhaled by you or your neighbors. Also, scraping is much easier to clean up after. Once you've got it scraped clean, you can sand smooth if necessary.

Comment: For all that cost and expense you could just about wrap them with steel and have a much better looking outcome.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a water based paint was applied over an oil based paint with the way it's peeling off. You might have to sand off two layers of paint to get to the wood. I'd use an 80 grit to remove the paint but don't press too hard or you'll damage the wood. Use bondo or wood filler, not caulk because many caulks are not paintable and you don't realize it until it's too late.. Prime and paint. You might only need one coat of paint if you get a quality paint.

Comment: There are a ton of paintable caulks.  If this cracking was due to shrinkage or movement, a rigid filler like Bondo is just gonna crack again.  I would use a paintable sealant, such as OSI Quad Max.

Comment: @Huesmann  Yes, and there are 4 tons of non paintable ones. These cracks were probably never filled in the first place, just painted over. Probably little or no shrinkage so wood filler would work fine.  No reason for DV.

Comment: It isn't hard to determine if a caulk is paintable; look at the label, and if you're feeling paranoid smear a sample on a scrap board and test it. Though I agree that the "cracks" in the photo just look like places where boards were butted together and nailed, probably were just painted over, and might be able to just be primed and painted again -- yes, the crack might recur, but by the time it does you may be due for another pass of paint anyway. (My place is overdue for painting, and I'm seriously tempted to have the soffit boards replaced with plastic on general principles.)

Answer (score 0):

Because it's peeling, I'd use a putty knife with a semi-sharp edge to peel it all off, then sand and re-seal it. Use a paintable caulking (personal pref.) or wood filler. Let it sit for a day then soft sand and prime the surface. Soft sand again and paint with the final color.

Answer (score 0):

Peeling is typically caused by poor surface preparation.

In this instance I would scrape any loose paint and use [XIM Peel Bond](https://www.rustoleum.com/product-catalog/consumer-brands/xim/primers-sealers/peel-bond). The Peel Bond acts like a glue and locks the edges down preventing future peeling. I have used this product extensively, it works great.

After you have scraped, cleaned and applied the Peel Bond you can apply a bead of paintable exterior grade caulking (check cure time before painting, OSI Quad requires 14 days I believe), paint with a latex exterior paint and you should be just fine.

[image: XIM Peel Bond primer]